# How can I do a python keyword search and word counter within all csvs files in directory and write to a single csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, glob, traversal

Im new to python and trying to understand certain libraries. Not sure how to upload a csv to SO but this script works with any csv, just replace 'SwitchedProviders_TopicModel'

My objective is to loop through all csv's in a file directory - C:\Users\jj\Desktop\autotranscribe and to write my python script outputs by file to a csv.

So let us say for example I have these csv files in the above folder-

'1003391793_1003391784_01bc7e411408166f7c5468f0.csv'
'1003478130_1003478103_8eef05b0820cf0ffe9a9754c.csv'
'1003478130_1003478103_8eef05b0820cf0ffe9a9882d.csv'

I want my python app(below) to do a word counter for each csv in the folder/directory and write the output to a dataframe like this -

```
csvname                                            pre existing  exclusions  limitations  fourteen
1003391793_1003391784_01bc7e411408166f7c5468f0.csv    1           2           0            1
```

my script -

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

def search_multiple_strings_in_file(file_name, list_of_strings):
    """Get line from the file along with line numbers, which contains any string from the list"""
    line_number = 0
    list_of_results = []
    count = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    # Open the file in read only mode
    with open("SwitchedProviders_TopicModel.csv", 'r') as read_obj:
        # Read all lines in the file one by one
        for line in read_obj:
            line_number += 1
            # For each line, check if line contains any string from the list of strings
            for string_to_search in list_of_strings:
                if string_to_search in line:
                    count[string_to_search] += line.count(string_to_search)
                    # If any string is found in line, then append that line along with line number in list
                    list_of_results.append((string_to_search, line_number, line.rstrip()))
 
    # Return list of tuples containing matched string, line numbers and lines where string is found
    return list_of_results, dict(count)


matched_lines, count = search_multiple_strings_in_file('SwitchedProviders_TopicModel.csv', [ 'pre existing ', 'exclusions','limitations','fourteen'])
    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(count, orient='index').reset_index()
df.columns = ['Word', 'Count']

print(df)
```

How would I be able to do this? Only looking for a counter specific words as you can see in my script like'fourteen', not looking for a counter for all words

Sample data of one of the csvs - credit user Umar H

```
df = pd.read_csv('1003478130_1003478103_8eef05b0820cf0ffe9a9754c.csv')
print(df.head(10).to_dict())
{'transcript': {0: 'hi thanks for calling ACCA  this is many speaking could have the pleasure speaking with ', 1: 'so ', 2: 'hi ', 3: 'I have the pleasure speaking with my name is B. as in boy E. V. D. N. ', 4: 'thanks yes and I think I have your account pulled up could you please verify your email ', 5: "sure is yeah it's on _ 00 ", 6: 'I T. O.com ', 7: 'thank you how can I help ', 8: 'all right I mean I do have an insurance with you guys I just want to cancel the insurance ', 9: 'sure I can help with that what was the reason for cancellation '}, 'confidence': {0: 0.73, 1: 0.18, 2: 0.88, 3: 0.72, 4: 0.83, 5: 0.76, 6: 0.83, 7: 0.98, 8: 0.89, 9: 0.95}, 'from': {0: 1.69, 1: 1.83, 2: 2.06, 3: 2.13, 4: 2.36, 5: 2.98, 6: 3.17, 7: 3.65, 8: 3.78, 9: 3.93}, 'to': {0: 1.83, 1: 2.06, 2: 2.13, 3: 2.36, 4: 2.98, 5: 3.17, 6: 3.65, 7: 3.78, 8: 3.93, 9: 4.14}, 'speaker': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 'Negative': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 0.116, 9: 0.0}, 'Neutral': {0: 0.694, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 0.802, 4: 0.603, 5: 0.471, 6: 1.0, 7: 0.366, 8: 0.809, 9: 0.643}, 'Positive': {0: 0.306, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.198, 4: 0.397, 5: 0.529, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.634, 8: 0.075, 9: 0.357}, 'compound': {0: 0.765, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.5719, 4: 0.7845, 5: 0.5423, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.6369, 8: -0.1779, 9: 0.6124}}
```

Comment: can you add a sample of one of the files you're parsing? it's not 100% clear what you're trying to saerch for.

Comment: Hey @Umar.H thanks for your response. not sure how to attach csv files here, fairly new to SO. please let me know and i will do the same.

Comment: you can add the first 10 rows of your fiel as paste it as text, or you can load it into a pandas dataframe `df = pd.read_csv(your_file)` then run `print(df.head(10).to_dict())` and paste the output here so we can reproduce your file.

Comment: Hi @Umar.H I did the same as you mentioned. Please see edited question

Comment: is `transcript` the column to parse in all the csv files?

Comment: @Umar.H Yes the word counter should only look for words in the transcript column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps -

1. Define input path
2. Extract all CSV files
3. count
4. Create 1 result dict add the name of the file and the Counter dict.
5. Finally, convert the resulting dict to dataframe and Transpose. (Fill NAN values with 0 if required)

```
import string
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd

inp_dir = Path(r'C:/Users/jj/Desktop/Bulk_Wav_Completed')  # current dir


def search_multiple_strings_in_file(file_name, list_of_strings):
    """Get line from the file along with line numbers, which contains any string from the list"""
    list_of_results = []
    count = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    # Open the file in read only mode
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
        # Read all lines in the file one by one
        for line_number, line in enumerate(read_obj, start=1):
            # For each line, check if line contains any string from the list of strings
            for string_to_search in list_of_strings:
                if string_to_search in line:
                    count[string_to_search] += line.count(string_to_search)
                    # If any string is found in line, then append that line along with line number in list
                    list_of_results.append(
                        (string_to_search, line_number, line.rstrip()))

    # Return list of tuples containing matched string, line numbers and lines where string is found
    return list_of_results, dict(count)


result = {}
for csv_file in inp_dir.glob('**/*.csv'):
    print(csv_file) # for debugging
    matched_lines, count = search_multiple_strings_in_file(csv_file, ['nation', 'nation wide', 'trupanion', 'pet plan', 'best', 'embrace', 'healthy paws', 'pet first', 'pet partners', 'lemon',
                                                                    'AKC', 'akc', 'kennel club', 'club', 'american kennel', 'american', 'lemonade'
                                                                    'kennel', 'figo', 'companion protect', 'true companion',
                                                                    'true panion', 'trusted pals', 'partners' 'lemonade', 'partner',
                                                                    'wagmo', 'vagmo', 'bivvy', 'bivy', 'bee' '4paws', 'paws', 'pet best',
                                                                    'pets best', 'pet best'])
    print(count)  # for debugging
    result[csv_file.name] = count
df = pd.DataFrame(result).T.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

**Output -**

```
       exclusions  limitations  pre existing
1.csv           1            3             1
2.csv           1            3             1
```

Comment: I am only looking for certain words as I mentioned in my python script. So I will not require a word counter for all words in all csvs

Comment: @JayTaggert I've updated my answer to filter the required word.

Comment: it is showing 0 for all word counts and only showing two words, limitations and exclusions instead of 4

Comment: @JayTaggert Try now once. I've used your function to evaluate the count

Comment: the output now has 0 columns and says the index displays all my csvs. there are no word count values either unfortunately

Comment: Can you try to print the count returned by your function?? It's working for me

Comment: Nk03. thanks for your response. Im receiving the same error as before and my count of rows is 432 but cols is 0.also, im not sure what is 1.csv and 2.csv in the output? it should be a list of all csvs in that particular directory. So why should a specific csv be mentioned in with open("1.csv", 'r') as read_obj:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231717/discussion-between-nk03-and-jay-taggert).

Answer (score 1):

As you've tagged pandas we can use `.str.extractall` to search for the word and line number.

You can extend the functions and add some error handling (like what will happen if transcript does not exist in a given csv file).

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

def get_files_to_parse(start_dir : str) -> list:
    
    files = [f for f in Path(start_dir).glob('*.csv')]
    return files
```

---

```
def search_multiple_files(list_of_paths : list,key_words : list) -> pd.DataFrame:
    dfs = []
    for file in list_of_paths:
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        word_df = df['transcript'].str.extractall(f"({'|'.join(key_words)})")\
                        .droplevel(1,0)\
                        .reset_index()\
                        .rename(columns={'index' : f"{file.parent}_{file.stem}")\
                        .set_index(0).T
        dfs.append(word_df)
    return pd.concat(dfs)
```

---

#### Usage.

using your example dataframe (i added in a few key words from your list)

```
files = get_files_to_parse('target\dir\folder')


[WindowsPath('1003478130_1003478103_8eef05b0820cf0ffe9a9754c.csv'),
 WindowsPath('1003478130_1003478103_8eef05b0820cf0ffe9a9754c_copy.csv')]
```

---

```
search_multiple_files(files,['pre existing', 'exclusions','limitations','fourteen'])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Umar after I run the last line of search_multiple_files i receive the error 
  File "C:\Users\jj\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 516, in get_result
    indexers[ax] = obj_labels.get_indexer(new_labels)

  File "C:\Users\jj\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3172, in get_indexer
    "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: @JayTaggert most likely you have dupe file names, (i assume in different directories?)

Comment: yes I do. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @JayTaggert not tested but something but adding the parent before the filename should work.

Comment: Hi Umar. thanks for your response. im new to python and not sure what you mean by the term adding 'parent' before filename. if you could edit your answer, i would be very thankful

Comment: @JayTaggert I did edit my answer see the line `f"{file.parent}_{file.stem}")`

Comment: i fixed a syntax error for the edit you made. it needed an extra } in the end, but unfortunately it is giving the same error as before of reindexing